# Print Multiple Lines on one Line in Python

Tags: python, c#, python-3.x, loops, python-3.7

So I mainly code in Python however have coded using C# due to my major one thing in C# is being able to write on the same line using "Write" for example

```
  int Num_Asteriks = 20.    
  for (int x = 0; x < NUM_ASTERIKS; ++x)
     Write("*");//Creates the top boarder for the company motto
```

that was in C#. Im wondering if there is a way to do this in python ive tried the code listed below with no luck. It just prints on multiple lines

```
x = 0
asteriks = 15
while x != asteriks:
    print('*',)
```

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/493386/how-to-print-without-newline-or-space

Answer (score 1):

by default `end='\n'` which means a newline

this may work.

```
for i in range(20):
    print("*", end='')
```

Comment: This worked actually, don't know why I didn't think of this. Can you explain the  end = ' '  part for me? what exactly does that do?

Comment: @SpacedOutKID end=' ' means, where you want to start writing the 2nd element, by default it is "in new line" (end='\n'), if you don't want the 2nd element to be printed in new line you have to specify that by writing end=' ' so that the 2nd element prints after a space not in new line.

Comment: when you print something the python interpreter add the character you specify in the end argument. By default, it is \n which means go to a new line. In your case we change it to "" so it stay on the same line.

Comment: @lovishkumar I appreciate the explanation! helped a lot

Comment: @AbdeslemSMAHI Wanted to say thanks to you too only could tag one tho, I appreciate the help!